# Net core aAction constraint from Controller route

Tags: asp.net-core

I use Attribute routing in my Net Core API.

I want to constraint parameter from the controller route in my Action methods.
And have same action methods that are constrained to the different category.

My controller route is:

```
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/{category}/[controller]")]
```

I would like to constraint category to my Action Methods:

```
[Route("{category:sample1}")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<SampleOneDto> GetById([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    return new SampleTwoDto();
}

[Route("{category:sample2}")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<SampleTwoDto> GetById([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    return new SampleTwoDto();
}
```

Don't pay attention that my category query parameter is before controller name. That must be like that, category is just placeholder.

My question is just - can I achieve this?

Comment: If it's just a single allowed category for an endpoint, could you just use something like `[Route("sample1")]` instead?

Comment: But how can I constraint "{category}" from the controller route in the Action Method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "constraint"?

Comment: I have {category} propery in the controller route. I would like to have same action methods but for different Categories. To constraint them in the Attribute. Where {category} property from the controller route is {sample1} and other method is {category} is {sample2}  

Like I said in question. Category is placeholder, I just need somehow to get this workflow to work.